# HighCharts Bar graph: Showing Bar Value when hovering the mouse

Tags: javascript, highcharts, jsfiddle

I got a bar graph like the one on this JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked column chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -30,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                    style: {
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        }]
    });
});
```

I wish I could see each bar section's value only when the mouse hovers each piece of the bar. For instance, placing the mouse over the green section of the Apple's bar would show up 3, placing the mouse over the blue part of the Grapes' bar would show 7. How could I do it?

Answer (score 1):

code:

```
plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,//make false here
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                    style: {
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/g075joyq/1/)

Comment: It solves part of the problem. But still I am not able to view the numbers when moving my mouse over the bar.

Comment: @lhidan : do you want only one value to be displayed and not the total value while hovering over the bar ?